# Natural deduction using Modus Tollens

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I was thinking about how to proof this:

$(a \implies b) \vdash (\lnot a \implies c) \implies (\lnot c \implies b)$

I want to solve it using Modus Tollens. Has anyone got an hint on this?

My ideas so far:

$1: a \implies b$ *premises*

$2: \lnot a \implies c$ *assume*

$ ... $

$\lnot c \implies b$

$(\lnot a \implies c) \implies (\lnot c \implies b)$ *implication introduction*

Any ideas/hints?

Comment: I don't see any way this can be true with the letters given.....you have nothing about p,q,r in the premise,  and  p=true,  r=false,  q=false gives false.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it!

Comment: Been a while since I did this in formal logic.  But you can just take the contrapositive of your assumption, to get $\lnot c \implies a$,  and then transitivity should get you there

Comment: By contra positive you mean $\lnot(\lnot a \implies c)?$

Comment: Contraposition is $(P\to Q)\to (\neg Q\to\neg P)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1. & a\to b & \mathsf P1 \\
\quad 2. & \neg a \to c & \textsf{Assume}\\
\qquad 3. & \neg c & \textsf{Assume} \\
\qquad 4. & a & \textsf{Why?} \\
\qquad 5. & b &  \textsf{How?} \\ \hline
\quad 6. & \neg c \to b & 3,5 , \to\textsf{Introduction}\\ \hline
7. & (\neg a \to c)\to(\neg c \to b) & 2, 6 \to\textsf{Introduction}
\end{array}